# Code That Only Executes if Try Does Not Catch

Tags: c#, try-catch

On a button click I am saving info to a Sqlite database.  I have the command.ExecuteNonQuery() in a try block.  I have got everything handled just find if the catch block is caught, but if everything makes it through just fine I want other code to execute that would clear out the values of my EditTexts and set focus.  I try putting that code after the ExecuteNonQuery() in my try block, but it still executes before the catch block even if an exception is caught so the values of my edittexts get cleared out before the catch block can even do anything.  Same story if I add the code after my try/catch block entirely.  The catch block seems to be the last thing executing and by then the values have been cleared and the catch block can't even execute properly. How do I set the values to clear only after the catch block is cleared and no exceptions are thrown?

EDIT: Tried putting it in a finally block but the same thing. Locals window shows both partnumber.Text and partQty.text are blank by the time they get to the catch block. But if I take out the code that clears those fields then both still have their values in the catch block. Is there something special maybe about Sqlite exceptions that would create a timing issue?

```
        try
    {
        c.ExecuteNonQuery();
        partnumber.Text = "";
        partqty.Text = "";
        partnumber.RequestFocus();
    }
    catch (SqliteException ex)
    {
        if (ex.ErrorCode.ToString() == "Constraint")
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.SetTitle("Item Duplication");
            builder.SetMessage("You have already counted this item.  How would you like to proceed?");
            builder.SetPositiveButton("Add to Previous", delegate
            {
                var newQty = Convert.ToInt32(test.currQuantity(partnumber.Text)) + Convert.ToInt32(partqty.Text);
                var n = connection.CreateCommand();
                connection.Open();
                n.CommandText = "Update [Items] Set Quantity = '" + newQty.ToString() + "' Where ItemNmbr = '" + partnumber.Text + "'";
                n.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Quantity updated to: " + newQty.ToString(), ToastLength.Long)
                    .Show();
                partnumber.Text = "";
                partqty.Text = "";
                partnumber.RequestFocus();
                connection.Close();
                return;
            });
            builder.SetNegativeButton("Override Previous", delegate
            {
                var n = connection.CreateCommand();
                connection.Open();
                n.CommandText = "Update [Items] Set Quantity = '" + partqty.Text + "' Where ItemNmbr = '" + partnumber.Text + "'";
                n.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Quantity updated to: " + test.currQuantity(partnumber.Text), ToastLength.Long)
                    .Show();
                partnumber.Text = "";
                partqty.Text = "";
                partnumber.RequestFocus();
                connection.Close();
                return;
            });
            var dialog = builder.Create();
            dialog.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.SetTitle("Error");
            builder.SetMessage(ex.Message.ToString());
            var dialog = builder.Create();
            dialog.Show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you want the "clear out" code ONLY to execute if there is no exception, or should it execute anyway, just after the exception is caught and handled?

Comment: if an exception is thrown in your try block the execution jumps immediately to the related catch block and to the calling code if no matching catch block is found. In no case the code after the line which throws the exception is executed within the try block. Debug better and check what is clearing those strings, it cannot be anything after the executeNonQuery if the exception is thrown exactly at that line.

Comment: So you're saying that code immediately after ExecuteNonQuery() gets executed even if ExecuteNonQuery() throws? That's not right, so something else must be going on. Are you sure the exception is coming from that line?

Comment: I need them to clear out regardless of if exceptions are thrown.  But I still need the values of both fields if an exception is thrown for use in my catch block.  Only after either the exception is handled or no exception is found should the fields clear out.

Comment: @jmease then you should put the code in a `finally` block

Comment: Then you need to use finally, but you didn't say that in the original question.

Comment: Perhaps partnumber.RequestFocus is throwing the exception? You need to check the exact line the exception is being thrown on. As Davide said, when an exception is thrown any following lines (in the same try) will not be executed.

Comment: I wrote my answer below before all this discourse and after reading it, it seems like you just really need a finally block.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try putting them in a finally block.

```
try {/*execute code*/}
catch(System.Exception e){/*handle exceptions*/}
finally {/*clean up regardless if an exception was thrown or not*/}
```

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood what is being asked here, but I was under the impression that they only wanted the code to execute if an exception wasn't thrown.

Comment: @M.Babcock the question title is misleading. He wants the cleanup to happen in all cases, just not before the exceptions are caught.

Comment: tried putting it in a finally block but the same thing. Locals window shows both partnumber.Text and partQty.text are blank by the time they get to the catch block.  But if I take out the code that clears those fields then both still have their values in the catch block.  Is there something special maybe about Sqlite exceptions that would create a timing issue?

Comment: OMG I feel so dumb.  The problem was that the executeNonQuery was in a loop that executed multiple sql statements.  It is the 2nd SQL statement that is catching but the finally block is clearing out the values during the 1st SQL statement.  Since technically the finally block was what I need to clear the values either way, I am accepting this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Place a `bool` before your "try" block and set it to a value. If you show an alert, set the bool to the opposite value and then proceed based upon that.

```
bool EverythingIsFine = true;
try{
     //Your code
}
catch(Exception){
    if(Condition){
        EverythingIsFine = false;
        ShowRelatedAlerts();
    }
}
if(!EverythingIsFine){
    //DoMoreStuff
}
```

Comment: It answers the title, but not the question. It also uses a code pattern that is unnecessarily complex.

Comment: finally does this and is already part of the framework, also he wants the cleanup to always happen

Comment: Actually I was a bit dizzy after reading the full question, so I read the last part again - namely "How do I set the values to clear only after the catch block is cleared and no exceptions are thrown?" And that's what I answered. I don't think this is "unnecessarily complex" - it's clear in its execution if nothing else.

Comment: He has a requirement that some part of the "executes after" only happens if certain things "happened" within a catch. If the catch executed but none of his conditions were true, he didn't want the additional code. At least from what I read. And that's how I answered.

Answer (score 1):

Execution inside a try block stops immediately if an exception is thrown. Therefore, the last line of a try block is only executed if no exceptions are raised.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have similar code in the catch block, I am pretty sure this is what's being executed and not the code after your Sql Statement that is throwing the error

put a break point after the statement that is throwing the exception and you will see that it's not being hit.

Answer (score 0):

to provide a bit more context to [NotMyself's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8658854/10639)

```
   try
    {
        c.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (SqliteException ex)
    {
       // at this point the values in the partNumber textbox haven't been cleared out
       showAlerts(ex);
    }
    finally 
    {
        // clear the textbox after the code in the try block 
        // and the code in the catch block have executed (IF it executed)
        partnumber.Text = "";
        partqty.Text = "";
        partnumber.RequestFocus();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [try-catch-finally](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dszsf989%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

```
    try
    {
       // Try something
    }
    catch (System.IO.IOException e)
    {
       // Handle exception
    }
    finally
    {
       // Some cleanup
    }
```